# iOS Annotation callout label overlaps right button

Tags: ios, annotations, callout

I have an iPhone app with code to create an annotation on a map. The annotation has a callout with right and left buttons and a label. It is all very basic there is no custom code. When I run the app with a long string for the label the text runs under the right button on the callout. The button is still functional but it looks ugly. I wanted to post an image of this but I need 10 rep. Has anyone ever seen this before and if so how did they solve it?

The annotation code is very basic:

```
#import "AddressAnnotation.h"

@implementation AddressAnnotation

@synthesize coordinate;
@synthesize mTitle;
@synthesize mSubTitle;
@synthesize event;

- (NSString *)subtitle{
    return mSubTitle;
}
- (NSString *)title{
    return mTitle;
}

-(id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) c{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        coordinate = c;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23378315/how-to-prevent-mkannotationview-callout-title-text-from-overlapping-with-right-a.  A minimum width of 320 for the MKMapView seems to be required to avoid this callout title overlap issue.

Comment: Please make your comment an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 7, unfortunately, a minimum width of 320 for the `MKMapView` seems to be required to avoid this callout title overlap issue (if you're using the default callout).

iOS 6 handles the title truncation correctly.